# after reloading the asp page why textbox text will goes to blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

After reloading the page how can i get the previous values in that textbox again.

Because when that page reload then textbox value goes blank?

How can I do this using javascript and jquery?

Comment: How are the values filled initially ?  From a database ? By the user ?  there's not enough information here to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically save POST values with javascript or jquery (though it is probably possible)

You need to do something like `<input type="text" value=" <? printf(POST['field']); ?>">`

Comment: Is it in classic asp?
value=" <? printf(POST['field']); ?>">

Comment: I have done this:
<input type="text" maxlength="50" value="<? printf(POST['srttextbox1']); ?>" name="srttextbox1">

But its not working.Please advise

Comment: I don't know ASP. Print the value of the field in the POST array to the screen inside the value="" attribute on the HTML element. Surely you know how to echo or print values in ASP.

Comment: Try `Response.Write(Request.Form("strtextbox1"));` or something like that.

Comment: Reloading the page is what he is after and this does not post the values.

Comment: If you refresh a page that has been sent POST data through a form, the browser will confirm if you want to resend the form data. If you click yes, then the code will absolutely post the values. If you hit no, then of course the browser will clear the POST data. If you want to hold on to that data, you would have to store it in a session.